# Why has arctan in Taylor series a range from $|x|\le1$

Tags: taylor-expansion, definition

as you can see here:

[image: my problem]

Arctan x has a range from $|x|\le1$ ,but normally it is R.

Why is it different. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Because the maclaurin series (taylor about $a=0$) for $\arctan$ converges only when $|x|\leq 1$ and $x\neq\pm i$. Read about [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of a power series.

Comment: BTW the domain of the $\arctan(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ not $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I copied wrong domain...

Comment: The derivative $1/(1+x^2)$ has a discontinuity in $\Bbb C$ at $x=\pm i$ so the power series for $\arctan x$ cannot converge for $|x|>1.$ What $\Bbb C $ has to do with it can be understood with some of the theory of complex calculus. "The shortest path to truth in $\Bbb R$ is thru $\Bbb 
 C$."-- Hadamard.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mid x \mid \le 1$ means the Taylor representation for $\arctan{x}$ about $0$ converges only for any $x$ has absolute value less than $1$. Even if you only consider real number, domain of $\arctan{x}$ is the whole real line, only the range is from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

You've got $x^{2n+1}$ in the series. Consider how $x^n$ grows, as $n$ approaches $\infty$. Do different things happen when $-1<x<1$ or when $x>1$ or $x<-1$?. Also, consider that for a series to converge, its terms need to get smaller. How does the rate of growth of $x^{2n+1}$ compare with that of $(2n+1)$?

Comment: The way this is phrased doesn't really talk about a difference between the series for arctan and some ofther power series with a different radius of convergence, like the series for the exponential function.

Comment: Right, but this isn't the exponential function. I'm making the case that $x^n$ grows without bound when $x>1$, which is always true. If OP wants to find out why the Taylor series for $\exp(x)$ converges, they would also have to consider that other terms in the series can grow as fast as $x^n$. But to do that, they'd need to already know that $x^n$ approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a function has a power series representation.  What this means is for some domain, we can express the function as this power series.  The domain of this function can be bigger, but our representation of the function as a power series may not be valid there.  As for why the representation for the taylor series of $tan(x)$ is only true for $|x| \leq 1$, consider how we derive it.

It's only for when $|x| \leq 1$

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 +  ...$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x +x^2 -x^3 +x^4 ...$$
Integrating both sides
$$arctan(x) = x -\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} ...$$

But again, this was only true for when $|x| \leq 1$

Now once you have that this true for when $|x| \leq 1$, it's natural to ask if the domain can be extended, and it turns out that it cannot.